# Omit "while" before -ing form

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

Can I omit "while" before -ing form? Are these two the same in terms of meaning?

- I **think** *while* walking.
- I **think** walking.

I can see a problem with different verbs:

- I **learn** *while* walking.
- I **learn** walking.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Are you asking whether you can say *I think walking* instead of *I think while walking*? If that's what you mean, (a) please [edit] your question to make that clear, and (b) the answer is only if the first verb *can't* take the second as an object. *I can think walking* is ambiguous since walking might be the object of think, whereas *I can walk chewing gum* is unambiguous. The grammar experts may be able to explain why in better terms than this :-)

Comment: @Chappo What immediately came to my mind when reading *I can walk chewing gum* was somebody dragging a piece of chewing gum behind them on a leash.

Comment: @JasonBassford that occurred to me too! I had thought of finding a better example, but ultimately I couldn't resist the ironic allusion to "walking and chewing gum at the same time".

Comment: @Chappo Thank you, you probably answered my question. I edited the question to clarify the meaning to what you suggested.

Comment: So, summarising the comments, the answer is: yes, it is grammatical, but if there is a more likely interpretation, then it is not likely to be understood

Comment: So, for the 2 examples you've given, omitting *while* changes the most obvious meaning. *I think walking* would be interpreted as "I think *about* walking" or "I think that walking *is the answer*" (etc, depending on context).